# Combining information in two data frames and calculating percentages over time

Tags: r, dataframe

I got two data frames: one with the dates of different sampling events, and another one with the connectivity of a river indicated with 0, 1, or 2 for each day of the year.

Now I would like to calculate the number (or percentage) of days that a certain connectivity occurred for each sample between sampling date and 6 months before (180 days).

My two data frames look like this:

> ```
> Date <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by="days")
> df <- data.frame(Date)
> df$Connect <- round(runif(2192, min=0, max=2),0)
> ```

> ```
> Sample_nr <- c(1:100) 
> df2 <- data.frame(Sample_nr) 
> df2$Date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2015/07/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"), 100)
> ```

What would be a elegant approach to get this data?

Thank you!

Cheers, Twan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be particularly elegant, but it is pretty simple. First some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
Date <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by="days")
Connect <- sample(0:2, 2192, replace=TRUE)
C0 <- cumsum(mydata$Connect==0)
C1 <- cumsum(mydata$Connect==1)
C2 <- cumsum(mydata$Connect==2)
mydata <- data.frame(Date, Connect, C0, C1, C2)
```

Now `mydata` contains your original columns plus cumulative sums for the three connectivity types. We need to draw the sample of dates beginning at `mydata[181, ]` because values before that do not have 180 day previous measurements:

```
sample <- sample(mydata$Date[181:2192], 5)
end <- which(mydata$Date %in% sample)
begin <- end - 180
data.frame(Date = mydata$Date[end], mydata[end, 3:5] - mydata[begin, 3:5])
#            Date C0 C1 C2
# 262  2015-09-19 64 65 51
# 377  2016-01-12 59 65 56
# 494  2016-05-08 55 67 58
# 754  2017-01-23 57 64 59
# 1057 2017-11-22 57 66 57
```

The values are the number of each connectivity type over the previous 180 days.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed :)